# How can i put a single value in a single column with fputcsv

Tags: php, mysql, sql, csv

I want to export data from the database to a CSV file.

My PHP code is like this

```
$members = Db::getResult('select * from '.MEMBERS_TABLE_NAME.' order by '.MEMBERS_COLUMN_PREFIX.'_lastname, '.MEMBERS_COLUMN_PREFIX.'_firstname');

    $fileName = "../db_user_export".".csv";
    $handle = fopen($fileName, 'w+');
    fputcsv($handle, array_keys($members[0]));
    foreach ($members as $member) {
        fputcsv($handle, $member);
    }//foreach
    fclose($handle);
```

Now the output I get in the CSV is like this:

"COLUMN A" "COLUMN B" "COLUMN C",  "password,username,fistname",   "lastname,updated"  "loggedin,is_new"

But I want it like this:

"COLUMN A" "COLUMN B" "COLUMN C", "password" "username" "firstname".

Anyone who knows how to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use select * , instead select only the fields that you want

Comment: Well, I want ALL the values in the CSV file, but that was a little too much to type here. Sorry for the confusion.

Problem is that all the values comes in a single column. but I want each value in a new column

Answer (score 0):

Do not select all fields if you only want three of them in your output:

```
SELECT '.MEMBERS_COLUMN_PREFIX.'_password, '.MEMBERS_COLUMN_PREFIX.'_username, '.MEMBERS_COLUMN_PREFIX.'_firstname FROM '.MEMBERS_TABLE_NAME.' ORDER BY '.MEMBERS_COLUMN_PREFIX.'_lastname, '.MEMBERS_COLUMN_PREFIX.'_firstname'
```